# Eloquent JavaScript Chapter 7 Project: A Robot

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the book "Eloquent JavaScript" and I have an issue with the beginning of The Robot Project.

```
function buildGrpah(edges) {
 let graph = Object.create(null);
 function addEdge(from, to) {
   if (graph[from] == null) {
     graph[from] = [to];
   } else {
     graph[from].push(to); 
   }
 }
 for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) {
   addEdge(from, to); addEdge(to, from);
 }
 return graph;
};
```

I understand the main principle, but I don't get why we call `addEdge` function twice in the loop. Could you explain it to me, please?

Comment: It's making two links one `from -> to` and then one `to -> from`. So you get a bidirectional link `from <-> to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the use of "from" and "to" variables a bit confusing. They switch values in the second call to addEdge. Ill try to explain..

buildGraph takes a list of location pairs. Location pairs just mean that those two locations have a direct connection.

addEdge returns an object with the same number of properties as there are unique locations mentioned in the location pairs. Each property corresponds to a unique location, and its value is a list of all the other locations that the property key location is connected to.

In a nutshell, addEdge is called twice because first it treats the first value in the location pair as the "from" or origin location (addEdge returned object property key) - and adds the second location to its list of directly connected places, and then it treats the second location as the origin, and adds the first location to its list of reachable locations.

The thing is that a location pair means that the fist location is accessible from the second, but also vice versa - so in the returned object - you want both locations in the value pair to have their own entries as property keys in the addEdge returned object, and then they need to have each other in their own list of reachable spots. pseudocodish example:

```
location pair: "red_house - blue_house"

addEdges return object: 
{
red_house: [blue_house],
blue_house: [red_house]
}
```

See how one location pair did two things? It set blue_house as reachable from red_house, and it set red_house as reachable from blue_house. This corresponds to how add Edge is called twice - inverting the parameters between the calls.

There are many ways to do the same thing when programming, and the author could have chosen to make the for...of loop only call addEdge once, then have the switch and doubled execution handled inside addEdge, but you can assume he decided that the repeated addEdge call in the for...of loop was a more elegant solution in this case - or better for some reason. These are the half artistic half engineering aspects of programming!

Below I am adding a little more breaking down of the buildGraph function and how the variables get switched around between the for...of loop - just in case someone could use a little more clarification.

You could look at buildGraph as three blocks:

1. addEdge function definition
2. for...of loop that calls addEdge twice
3. return graph statement

Part 2. (for...of loop) is executed first. This for...of loop goes through the whole "edges" array - dealing with one array element in each iterations.
Each edges element is a string in this format: "location_A - location_B" (for real example: "Marketplace-Post Office") .

The for...of loop uses destructuring to set declare and assign "from" and "to" variables - with "from" being assigned (as a value) the sting: "location_A, and "to" being assigned "location_B". The for...of loop then calls addEdge using  "from" and "to" as arguments.

What you might find confusing is that the "from" and "to" used as parameters when calling addEdge in the for...of loop statements, are not always the corresponding "from" and "to" inside addEdge. Thats because when the for...of loop calls addEdge twice, it switches the order of "from" and "to" between both calls to addEdge - first calling addEdge(**from, to**), then calling addEdge(**to, from**).

Now, even though the for...of loop switches the two variables when it calls addEdge, addEdge itself always calls its first parameter "from" and and its second parameter "to".

This means that in the first call: addEdge(**from, to**), the "from" and "to" from the for...of loop are the same "from" and "to" used inside the addEdge function, but in the second call: addEdge(**to, from**) - because the parameters are switched, the value (string) of the "from" used inside the addEdge function is actually the string value of the "to" of the for...of loop.